# How to uploade an Excel file to a Blob Storage as an Excel File

Tags: python, excel, io, azure-functions, azure-blob-trigger

i have a process that's beening triggered by Blobs. I'm trying to upload a dataframe to Azure blob storage and i can achieve this via this code.

```
async def main(myblob: func.InputStream,  outputblob: func.Out[str]) -> None:
(Some Code)
outputblob.set(Buch.to_string())
```

but the problem with that approach is that it uploads the DataFrames as a File and not as CSV or Excel file. I also tried this Code but this time nothing was uploaded.

```
outputblob.set(Deb.to_excel("Deb.xlsx"))
```

Is there anyway that we can uploade as Excel files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Solution is to upload it manually without using the Built-in function:

```
outputblob.set()
```

my code for uploading a CSV file to a container. works for HTTP and Blob Trigger.

```
def upload(_file,_connectionString,_containerName,_fileName):            
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(_connectionString)
        # Instantiate a new ContainerClient
        container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(_containerName)
        if not container_client.exists():
            # Create new Container in the service
            print("container does not exist. create it")
            container_client.create_container()
            properties = container_client.get_container_properties()
            # Instantiate a new BlobClient            
            blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(_fileName)
            # upload data
            blob_client.upload_blob(_file, blob_type="BlockBlob")
        else:
            blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=_connectionString,
                                                    container_name=_containerName,
                                                    blob_name=_fileName) 
            if blob.exists():
                logging.info(f'{_fileName} exists')                    
            else:
                # Instantiate a new BlobClient            
                blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(_fileName)
                # upload data
                blob_client.upload_blob(_file, blob_type="BlockBlob")
```

use it like This:

```
upload(YourDataFrame.to_csv(index=False, encoding = "utf-8"),_connectionString,_containerName,_fileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try and take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/Dminor7/247eeef734593f36cb750069de1be7fc

/Kenneth

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).